# md-no-focus-style does not work properly in my setup

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a button to open my navbar:

[image]

And after I click it it get's some kind of hitmarker:

[image]

After clicking on some navbar item (thus switching to next state/view) the hitmarker should disappear. Unforunately the hitmarker is present till I click on a random element.

The html for the button:

```
<div ng-controller="navbarCtrl" ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()" aria-label="Menu">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/img/menu.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h2>
          <span><a ui-sref="overview">Test</a></span>
        </h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ui-sref="account" aria-label="Account">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/img/account.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>

  </md-content>

  <section layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">
      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo" layout="row">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Menu</h1>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="close" ng-click="close()">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/img/closeNavbar.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </md-toolbar>
      <div layout="column" layout-align=" center">
        <md-button ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="close()" layout-align=" center" style="text-align:left" ui-sref="overview">Overview</md-button>
      </div>
    </md-sidenav>

  </section>

</div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

What do I have to change in order to fix this?

Comment: can you make a codepen or fiddle of this problem ?

Comment: Or whole code of `sidenav` ?

Comment: Sorry. But I don't understand your queston.

Comment: do you want to remove that effect when you click ?

Comment: heres the same question raises, when I click on the `md-button`, I dont want it to be focused, is there any property like `md-no-focus` as we have `md-no-ink`.

Thanks
#zeasts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this in your CSS:

```
.md-focused {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your CSS:

```
md-button:focus, md-icon:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```